# Convert range (non-continuous) to values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a very large range of complicated formulas that use an external data source. My users don't have access to this data source, therefore I want to convert the range to values before sending the sheet.

Range=

```
=VALs!$A$1,VALs!$D$1:$D$45,VALs!$F$1:$G$45,VALs!$I$1:$J$45,VALs!$N$1:$N$45,VALs!$R$1:$T$45,VALs!$V$1:$V$45,VALs!$X$1:$Y$45,VALs!$AB$1:$AB$45,VALs!$AE$1:$AE$45,VALs!$AT$1:$AT$45,VALs!$AW$1:$BB$45,VALs!$BD$1:$BD$45,VALs!$BG$1:$BG$45,VALs!$BK$1:$BK$45,VALs!$BQ$1:$BQ$45,VALs!$BT$1:$BT$45,VALs!$CC$1:$CD$45,VALs!$CJ$1:$CJ$45,VALs!$CN$1:$CN$45,VALs!$CP$1:$CQ$45,VALs!$CU$1:$CW$45,VALs!$DA$1:$DC$45,VALs!$DH$1:$DH$45,VALs!$DJ$1:$DJ$45,VALs!$DL$1:$DL$45,VALs!$DO$1:$DO$45,VALs!$DR$1:$DS$45,VALs!$DV$1:$DV$45,VALs!$DZ$1:$EA$45,VALs!$EV$1:$EV$45,VALs!$EY$1:$EY$45,VALs!$FB$1:$FC$45,VALs!$FE$1:$FL$45
```

Now:

- **Copy & paste as values** does not work on multiple selections
- **With Sheets("VALs").Range("values").CurrentRegion
  .Value = .Value** Does not work, I end up with empty cells in place of the range
- The range is dynamic and will change often, that's why it's named, there is a separate sub to create the range

Would anyone be able to help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something as simple as this? (In this case, the Named Range is named "RNG".)

```
Sub RangeToValues()
  For Each cel In Range("RNG").Cells
    cel.Value = cel.Value
  Next cel
End Sub
```

Or is the problem more complex and I didn't understand?

Comment: Appreciated, should have thought of doing iterating through cells.